# Dash in url (mapped to the action)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json-api

I try to implement an ASP.NET Web Api Controller that supports the JsonApi standard (http://jsonapi.org/ primarily used by Ember.js)

The URL's may contain a dash. But the corresponding method name in the C# code may not contain a dash.

My javascript try to POST to

```
http://localhost:50000/jsonapi/activity-exercises
```

But I am not able to implement an endpoint that can receive that request.
I have tried:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage ActivityExercises([FromBody] ActivityExerciseEntry value)
{
   // ...
```

Ideally there should be an attribute to add to the method to specify the mapped action name in the URL. Does such attribute exist?

My route mapping looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapHttpRoute("EmberJsonApi", "jsonapi/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "JsonApi", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the route via attribute on your action(s)? `[Route("jsonapi/activity-exercises")]`

Comment: Or ```[ActionName("activity-exercises")]```?

Comment: I'd suggest you switch to "Attribute" routing over "convention-based" routing since your URI's are well... unconventional (at least as far as .NET's concern) http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#ENABLE

Comment: Thank you @Rob. Attribute routing certainly looks promising.

Comment: Thank you @Shelby115. Attribute routing certainly looks promising.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. It took a lot of googling, because this is not very well documented....

As I suspected, there exists an attribute I could use: `[ActionName]`

So the endpoind definition just looks looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("activity-exercises")]
public HttpResponseMessage ActivityExercises([FromBody] ActivityExerciseEntry value)
{
   ...
```